# How can i erase contents in a Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, label

Sorry for the mess

so I am making a seating chart, and I cant seem to get it working properly... again. I am trying to make the label reset every time i press the run button, any ideas?

```
#commands: add name , Run

#imports
import random
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

#Console and background Handlers
Tables = 6
Names = []

def AddNames():
    NewNames = e.get("1.0", 'end -1c')
    if NewNames in Names:
        print("Name Already exists")
    elif NewNames == "":
        print("Empty")
    else:
        Names.append(NewNames)
    print(Names)
    e.delete(1.0, END)

def Random():
    RandomNum = random.randrange(Tables)
    if RandomNum == 0:
        RandomNum = random.randrange(Tables)
    return RandomNum

def run():
    X = 0
    for i in Names:
        #print(Names[X])
        print("Table: " + str(Random()))
        X += 1
#text = Label(popup, text = "")
        text = Label(popup, text=  Names[X] + "\n" + "Table: " +     str(Random()))
        text.pack()

#GUI Handler
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x768")

e = Text(root, bd = 10, font=("Comic Sans MS", 50) ,width = 15, height = 2)
e.pack()

popup = Toplevel()
popup.title("Seating Chart")

AddNameButton = Button(root, text = ("Add Name"), width = 15, height = 5,     command = AddNames)
AddNameButton.pack()

RunButton = Button(root, text = ("Run"), width = 15, height = 5, command = run)
RunButton.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to reset text every time the user presses the run button

Comment: Do you want the run function to only erase contents or it does something else too?

Comment: The run function kind of assigns the different names a number.

Comment: You already did it in `AddNames()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

import random

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.seatwindow = None

        self.root.title('Add Names')

        self.currentname = tkinter.StringVar()
        self._maxtables = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.addednames = []

        self.commandframe = ttk.Labelframe(self.root, text='Commands')

        self.nameentry = ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.currentname)
        self.addbutton = ttk.Button(self.root, text='Add Name', command=self.addname)
        self.maxtablabel = ttk.Label(self.root, text='Tables: ')
        self.maxtabentry = ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self._maxtables)

        self.genbutton = ttk.Button(self.commandframe, text='Run', command=self.generate)
        self.resetbutton = ttk.Button(self.commandframe, text='Reset', command=self.reset)

        self._maxtables.set('6')

        self.nameentry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.addbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.maxtabentry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsw')
        self.maxtablabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nse')

        self.genbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.resetbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.commandframe.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.nameentry.bind('<Return>', self.addname)
        self.root.bind('<Control-Return>', self.generate)

    def addname(self, event=None):
        name = self.currentname.get()
        if not(name == '' or name in self.addednames):
            self.addednames.append(name)
            self.currentname.set('')
        else:
            self.currentname.set('Name already added!')

    def generate(self, event=None):
        if not self.seatwindow == None:
            self.seatwindow.destroy()
        self.currentname.set('')
        self.seatwindow = tkinter.Toplevel()

        random.shuffle(self.addednames)
        tables = []
        for i in range(self.maxtables):
            tableframe = ttk.Labelframe(self.seatwindow, text='Table ' + str(i + 1) + ':')
            tableframe.grid(column=i, row=0, sticky='nsew')
            tables.append(tableframe)
        for index, name in enumerate(self.addednames):
            namelabel = ttk.Label(tables[index%self.maxtables], text=name)
            namelabel.grid(column=0, row=index//self.maxtables + 1)

    def reset(self):
        self.currentname.set('')
        self.maxtables = 6
        self.addednames = []

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    @property
    def maxtables(self):
        return int(self._maxtables.get())

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: its not the Text i want to clear, its the label(called text). e.delete(1.0, END) only clears the Text where the user inputs the names. maybe if you ran it on your pc(f available) you would see, my code is VERY messy XD.

Comment: Maybe I can create a new reset button that resets the text, but I don't know what to put into the function

Comment: Put some cleaner code, if this helps let me know, otherwise I can work through the problem using only your code.

Comment: yea, it worked. Did you just type this up!? if so, that is amazing!!! I will take a look at this and kinda process it. I'm a little new to tkinter and and little experience with python, please do explain it.

Comment: I did just type it up. :D But, I have also been programming in python for 5+ years. Let me know if you have any questions. Some elements of my code are fairly advanced features of python, but I will try to make it clear what it all does.

Comment: Sounds good. If you have any specific questions, let me know.

Comment: No problem. Always glad to help.

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you did. I spent a couple minutes reading the answer and don't know what part you added to solve the problem. Also, part of the code is not marked up properly.